# Cocos2d-x Google input method in Android

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

Cocos2d-x CCEditBox Lowercase default has been set .Android Google input method  capitalized. other input methods are normal lowercase.

```
    m_pEditText = CCEditBox::create(CCSizeMake(m_pEditTextPos->getContentSize().width, m_pEditTextPos->getContentSize().height),  CCScale9Sprite::create("transparent_1x1.png"));
    m_pEditText->setFontSize(24);
    m_pEditText->setFontName(DefaultFontName);
    m_pEditText->setFontColor(INTCOLOR_2_CCC3(0xdcfbff));
    m_pEditText->setReturnType(kKeyboardReturnTypeDone);
    m_pEditText->setInputMode(kEditBoxInputModeSingleLine);
//    m_pEditText->setInputFlag(kEditBoxInputFlagInitialCapsAllCharacters);
    m_pEditText->setReturnType(kKeyboardReturnTypeDefault);
//    m_pEditText->setMaxLines( 3 );
    m_pEditText->setMaxLength(20);
//    m_pEditText->setMaxLength(60);
    m_pEditText->setDelegate(this);
    editTextPos=m_pEditTextPos->getPosition();
    m_pEditText->setPosition(editTextPos);

    this->addChild(m_pEditText);
```

---